# Simple JavaScript bulk-download script for Humble Bundle library is only returning the last item

Tags: javascript, closures

Trying to make a small JavaScript that will download all my e-books (for example) on Humble Bundle. I realize that something like this has been done before, but all the solutions I've encountered so far work in the *purchases* section, not the *library*. I also realize that Humble Bundle, at some point, added a "bulk download" button on each e-book purchase page, making the aforementioned solutions obsolete.

I prefer not asking for help, but at this point, I just want to make my script work and learn why it is not. *I don't want to take the easy way out using any third-party add-on or application (e.g. download managers).* I have tried this in jQuery as well, but have gotten the same results below. Would like to do it in vanilla JS, but welcome any helpful suggestions!

Here is my code:

```
var domItem = document.querySelectorAll("div.selector-content div.text-holder h2"), domItemName, domItemDownload;
domItem.forEach(function(itemBtn) {
  itemBtn.click();
  domItemName = document.querySelector("div.details-holder div.details-heading div.text-holder h2");
  domItemDownload = document.querySelectorAll("div.details-holder div.js-button-holder div.js-download-button h4");
  domItemDownload.forEach(function(downloadBtn) {
    console.log(domItemName.innerText + ": " + downloadBtn.innerText);
    downloadBtn.click();
  });
});
```

What I expect to happen for each e-book is an output of the e-book name and type of e-book it is downloading (PDF, etc.) and then navigating to the URL obtained by clicking on the download button. An example of the URL is here: `https://dl.humble.com/torrents/unixpowertools.mobi.torrent?gamekey=xxxxx&ttl=xxxxx&t=xxxxx`.

This works as expected up to the point where it downloads *all* the torrent files: the browser console log will say that *it has navigated to each URL to download the needed file, but only the last entry gets downloaded*. For example, say I have three e-books and each of them have a PDF torrent file, the script will click everything as expected and the browser will say something like the following:

```
CSS Refactoring: PDF main.min.js:10:15514
CSS: The Definitive Guide: PDF main.min.js:10:15514 
D3 Data-Driven Documents Pocket Primer: PDF main.min.js:10:15514     
Navigated to https://dl.humble.com/torrents/cssrefactoring.pdf.torrent?gamekey=xxxxx&ttl=xxxxx&t=xxxxx
Navigated to https://dl.humble.com/torrents/css_thedefinitiveguide.pdf.torrent?gamekey=xxxxx&ttl=xxxxx&t=xxxxx
Navigated to https://dl.humble.com/torrents/d3datadrivendocuments_pocketprimer.pdf.torrent?gamekey=xxxxx&ttl=xxxxx&t=xxxxx
```

However, I will only get the torrent file for that last entry. No matter what type of e-book it is, whether it is a direct download or the torrent file, no matter where I start and end the loop, or whether I use Chrome or Firefox, I always download only the last entry's file.

So, after seeing that I can get the e-books' download URLs by clicking on the download buttons, I tried random ones directly in the browser and was able to download each of them individually, so I know the URLs are working as expected. To just get to an expected result, I then copy-pasted all the URLs in the console log and put them into an array. I then looped through the array with the following script, but still get the same result:

```
var urls = [
  'https://dl.humble.com/torrents/cssrefactoring.pdf.torrent?gamekey=xxxxx&ttl=xxxxx&t=xxxxx',
  'https://dl.humble.com/torrents/css_thedefinitiveguide.pdf.torrent?gamekey=xxxxx&ttl=xxxxx&t=xxxxx',
  'https://dl.humble.com/torrents/d3datadrivendocuments_pocketprimer.pdf.torrent?gamekey=xxxxx&ttl=xxxxx&t=xxxxx'
];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  document.location.href = urls[i];
};
```

Based on my research, this sounds just like a **closure issue**. However, using techniques like those found on https://dzone.com/articles/why-does-javascript-loop-only-use-last-value have not resolved the issue. Furthermore, my understanding of a closure issue is that I shouldn't be seeing the browser "navigating" to each URL, but instead expect it to say it is navigating to the *same* URL many times.

I also thought that maybe this was an issue with the browser trying to download too many files from the server too quickly, so I tried implementing a wait in three ways: `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, and wrote a function to while-loop until a specified time has elapsed (bad, I know). This still gave the same result, but slower.

I am sure the issue is something simple but having worked on and abandoned this particular task many times before, I just need a set of fresh, more experienced eyes on it.

This is my first post, so I appreciate your time reading this and let me know if there is any more information you may need or if I need to fix up my post.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to closures. When you click on a link, the browser closes the current page and opens a new one. If you click on another link while the page gets opened, the page will abort the loading process of the page and open the new one instead. You get the same behaviour with `.click()` will cause a redirect that aborts the previous ones, therefore the last page is opened.

Instead you could open each link in a new tab:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
   window.open(urls[i], "download");
 };
```

Comment: Makes sense; I knew it'd be something simple that I was overlooking. That works great on the second script, after getting the URLs from the first. However, doing it that way wasn't really my intention.

Comment: @edward you can easily adapt it in the first one, I guess the downloadButton is an `<a />` element?

Comment: Sorry, was trying to edit my comment and took too long. The way Humble Bundle appears to provide the URL link is only after clicking on the download div and I don't see any other way to get the URLs to use it fluidly in the second script's loop. It's not an `<a>` tag, but a series of `<div>` tags each with classes such as `js-download-button`, `js-disambiguate`, and so on.

So there is no "open in new tab" option in this case, and why I have to use `.click()` to simulate clicking on the DOM object.

Comment: In that case you have to only click one link whenever the page gets opened, then store a persistent counter in localStorage to take the next one on reload